# how to dynamically highlight marker based on passed data to google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to highlight the `marker` based on the scroll of the `div` the `div` is shown below

**My Html DOM**

```
<div data-value="data 1"></div>
<div data-value="data 2"></div>
<div data-value="data 3"></div>
<div data-value="data 4"></div>
```

**My javascript**

```
var cutoff = $(window).scrollTop() + 200;

$('div').each(function(){
    if($(this).offset().top + $(this).height() > cutoff){
        $('div').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        console.log($(this).data('value'));

        //callGoogleMapHere(data..);

        return false; // stops the iteration after the first one on 
    }
});
```

here is example of working code: http://jsfiddle.net/pdzTW/212/

As you have noted `callGoogleMapHere(data..);` in the above code, i want to call `google map` from there with `data` passed so that i can `Highlight` the `Marker` on map.

here is my map code link(thanks to geocodezip) : http://jsfiddle.net/2gz7h123/64/

**Question**: i want to highlight the `marker` dynamically on `Google map` passing `data` from this function  `callGoogleMapHere(data..);`

please help me thanks in advance!!!

Comment: please don't down vote already got so many down vote today itself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44397520/how-to-implement-multiple-marker-with-dynamic-highlight

Comment: if the other one was closed don't expect this one not to be closed

Comment: @guradio, this one is having relevant `code` and `data`  so i don't expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate that you are stuck and require help. However this is not a site in which people will simply do you work for you.

It appears that you lack the knowledge of what you are trying to achieve and simply want the work done. I therefore have a compromise which given the research you have conducted you should be able to obtain a plausible solution.

Given a set of divs

```
 <div data-value="0" class="notmap"></div>
 <div data-value="1" class="notmap"></div>
 <div data-value="2" class="notmap"></div>
 <div data-value="3" class="notmap"></div>
 <div data-value="4" class="notmap"></div>
```

we want to be able to call some function when they are **hovered** over. In your solution the same thing will be applied on the scroll.

using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert('please scroll output window and check the console');
  $(".notmap").hover(function() {
    highlightMarker($(this).data('value'));
  }, function() {
    stopHighlightMarker($(this).data('value'));
  });
});
```

this will call the `highlightMarker`function on hover and `stopHighlightMarker` when you stop hovering over the div.

The highlight marker does the following:

```
function highlightMarker(i) {
  if (markers[i].getAnimation() !== null) {
    markers[i].setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    markers[i].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}
```

Essentially I added an array of markers and it grabs the `markers[i]` element by passed through, the `data-value` number. Its a cheap way but hey-ho.

It then simple animates the icon so that it is visible and highlighted by bouncing up and down.

I appreciate that this is not *really* an answer to your question, but with the information I have provided should be sufficient to get your problem solved.

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/2gz7h123/68/

Comment: that is what i wanted

Comment: any other answers are much appriciated